# Add Button on the header Of Kanban View

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10

I'm using Odoo 10 and I want to add a button in the head of `hr.job`, Kanban View. 
How can I do it ?

Comment: Please, post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your button like this

```
<t t-extend="KanbanView.buttons">

 <t t-jquery="button" t-operation="after">

        <t t-if="widget.modelName == 'hr.job'">
             <button
                class="oe_button oe_highlight" 
                type="button">Your Button</button>
        </t>

    </t>
```